# Unable to connect spring boot producer app to kafka confluent topic

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Getting the below eeror-
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic topic_1 not present in metadata after 60000 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you do not have the bootstrap server url passed correctly

```
# kafka
spring.kafka.client-id=${service.name}
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS:localhost:9092}
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=MANUAL
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency=5
spring.kafka.properties.session.timeout.ms=15000
spring.kafka.properties.request.timeout.ms=30000
spring.kafka.properties.ConfiguredAvroSchemas=util.kafka.serialization.ConfiguredAvroSchemasImpl

spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=your_group_id
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=util.kafka.AvroClasspathDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.check.crcs=${KAFKA_CHECK_CRCS:false}

spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=.util.kafka.AvroNamedSchemaSerializer

# kafka TopicAutoCreator
service.kafka.topiccreator-autostart=true
service.kafka.partitions=16
service.kafka.replication-factor=3
```